# Verify if a function represents a wave using the standard wave equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

I was asked to prove the following function using the standard wave equation:

$$ y = kx^2-\omega t $$

So far, I have only answered trigonometric functions (such as the textbook example $ y = \sin(kx-\omega t) $ and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: All waves (for your scope) must be of the form $f(ax+bt)$ where $f$ is any arbitrary finite function and $a$ and $b$ are real coefficients.

Comment: Welcome to Phys.SE. Please, have a look at this site policy about home-work like questions: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 2):

- If a wave is defined as a solution of the wave equation $$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2},\tag{1}$$ then the function $y(x,t)=kx^2-\omega t$ does not satisfy the wave equation. So it is not a wave.
- If you define a wave as a periodic function of space and time, then the given $y(x,t)$ is neither periodic in $x$ nor periodic $t$. So it is not a wave.
- Finally, a sufficient condition (but not necessary). If a function $y(x,t)$ can be expressed in the form $y(x,t)=f(x+vt)+g(x-vt)$, where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions of the respective variables, you can show that $y(x,t)$ is a solution of the wave equation $(1)$.